# Bash script for checking if a host is on the local network

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that allows you to enter your machine name, and then lets you know if the host is on the local network. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the host you would like to ping:"

read host

if ping -c 1 -W 1 "$host";

    then

        echo "$host is up"

    else

        echo "$host is down"

fi
```

This allows me to enter my machine name (ubuntu) but doesn't actually let you know if it's on the local network or not (aside from looking at the IP and knowing that it's local).

I asked my TA for advice and after a week, this man's only response was 'ruptime.'

I'm not too sure how to incorporate that into a script that does what the question is asking. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute -m2 "$host"` comes to  mind.

And don't forget to look up "pipefail" in your shell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how does traceroute only show anything on the local network? Seems like it works similar to ping

Comment: traceroute shows each "hop" from your network to the target host. If you are on the same network you get one hop. If you go outside your network you use two or more hops, one hop for each network gateway, until the target is reached. 

ping just reports information on the last hop, the final target, and nothing about the inbetween steps. traceroute is all about the inbetween steps. 


Try traceroute on some big hosts and tiny hosts. It can be interesting.

Comment: traceroute is a wonderful diagnostic tool during times of network failures as it gives a strong hint on which step of your request failed. Especially if you know what typical routes to your target look like.  Beware that the routes can dynamically change depending on network load, speeds, etc.